# Property of solutions of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove the following:

"Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R^n}$ be an open set and $f\in C^k(\Omega), (x_0,y_0)\in\Omega$.

Show that the solutions of $y'=f(x,y)\ (x\in\mathbb{R},y\in\mathbb{R^n})$ belong to $C^{k+1}$."

My attempt:

By induction on $k.$

If $k=0$ then by Peano-Picard theorem there exists a solution $\phi\in C^1$ to the DE.

Suppose now that $f\in C^{k+1}(\Omega)$; then $f\in C^k(\Omega)$ so by inductive hypothesis there exists a solution $\phi\in C^{k+1}$ such that $\phi'=f(x,\phi(x))$ i.e. the derivative of $\phi$ is $C^{k+1}$ thus $\phi$ is $C^{k+2}$ and this closes the induction.

---

Can someone confirm that my proof is correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Your bootstrap argument seems ok.

Comment: For $k=0$ you cannot use the Picard theorem, but the Peano theorem (and you don't have, in general, uniqueness there). And to me, your induction is somewhat strange: I would take a **fixed** $k$, and then proceed by induction ($k$ times only!) from $\phi$ being $C^1$ to $\phi$ being $C^{k+1}$.